# Unable to execute any StrutsTestCase using Struts2-Junit-Plugin, action method is null

Tags: struts2, struts2-junit-plugin

First of all sorry if I don't explain it clearly enough, I will try to do my best. Recently I switched from C/C# to Java, and I'm a bit overwhelmed.

I'm working on a project that is using Struts2+Hibernate (I'm not using Spring); the idea was to use the struts2-JUnit-plugin to test the actions.

I followed the strut2-junit-plugin tutorial without success and after a lot of research and trying all the possible solutions posted everywhere I couldn't find the good one.

The "issues" (because I'm not really sure whether this is an issue or not...) I have is that when I try to run a StrutsTestCase, during the setUp:

```
super.setUp();
initServletMockObjects();
setupBeforeInitDispatcher();
dispatcher = initDispatcher(dispatcherInitParams);
setupAfterInitDispatcher(dispatcher);
```

When calling *dispatcher = initDispatcher(dispatcherInitParams)*,  *dispatcherInitParams* is null and it throws the following stack trace:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ERROR CdiObjectFactory [findBeanManager]: Could not find BeanManager instance for any given JNDI key, giving up
ERROR CdiObjectFactory Struts2 CDI integration could not be initialized.
ERROR DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor Conversion registration error
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts2.cdi.CdiObjectFactory.getInjectionTarget(CdiObjectFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.struts2.cdi.CdiObjectFactory.buildBean(CdiObjectFactory.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:177)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverterCreator.createTypeConverter(DefaultTypeConverterCreator.java:40)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.loadConversionProperties(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.processRequired(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.init(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:59)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InitializableFactory.create(InitializableFactory.java:45)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$8.call(ContainerBuilder.java:626)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$8.call(ContainerBuilder.java:623)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:555)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:623)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTestCaseHelper.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCaseHelper.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCase.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:216)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxx.xx.xxx.PasswordActionTest.setUp(PasswordActionTest.java:31)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
ERROR DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor Conversion registration error
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts2.cdi.CdiObjectFactory.getInjectionTarget(CdiObjectFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.struts2.cdi.CdiObjectFactory.buildBean(CdiObjectFactory.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:177)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverterCreator.createTypeConverter(DefaultTypeConverterCreator.java:40)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.loadConversionProperties(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.process(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:64)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.init(DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor.java:60)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InitializableFactory.create(InitializableFactory.java:45)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$8.call(ContainerBuilder.java:626)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$8.call(ContainerBuilder.java:623)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:555)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:623)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTestCaseHelper.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCaseHelper.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCase.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:216)
    at com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.PasswordActionTest.setUp(PasswordActionTest.java:31)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

After this, even that I got the error, I can continue testing, for instance, the following test:

```
@Test
public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {

    //set parameters before calling getActionProxy
    PasswordUpdate pu = new PasswordUpdate();
    pu.setCurrentPassword("current");
    pu.setNewPassword("new");
    pu.setNewPasswordConfirm("new");
    request.setParameter("passwordUpdate.currentPassword", pu.getCurrentPassword());
    request.setParameter("passwordUpdate.newPassword", pu.getNewPassword());
    request.setParameter("passwordUpdate.newPasswordConfirm", pu.getNewPasswordConfirm());

    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/UpdatePassword.action");
    assertNotNull(proxy);

    PasswordAction action = (PasswordAction) proxy.getAction();
    assertNotNull(action);

    String result = proxy.execute();
    assertEquals(Action.SUCCESS, result);
    assertNotNull(action.getPasswordUpdate());
    assertEquals("current", action.getPasswordUpdate().getCurrentPassword());
    assertEquals("new", action.getPasswordUpdate().getNewPassword());
    assertEquals("new", action.getPasswordUpdate().getNewPasswordConfirm());

}
```

The second issue is that it doesn't seem to find the action when calling:

> ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/UpdatePassword.action");

It's throwing an exception inside getActionProxy:

```
protected ActionProxy getActionProxy(String uri) {
        request.setRequestURI(uri);
        ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping(request);
        String namespace = mapping.getNamespace();
        String name = mapping.getName();
        String method = mapping.getMethod();

        Configuration config = configurationManager.getConfiguration();
        ActionProxy proxy = config.getContainer().getInstance(ActionProxyFactory.class).createActionProxy(
                namespace, name, method, new HashMap<String, Object>(), true, false);

        initActionContext(proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext());

        // this is normally done in onSetUp(), but we are using Struts internal
        // objects (proxy and action invocation)
        // so we have to hack around so it works
        ServletActionContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletActionContext.setRequest(request);
        ServletActionContext.setResponse(response);

        return proxy;
    }
```

At this point *String method* is null and the following call is throwing an exception:

> ActionProxy proxy =
>   config.getContainer().getInstance(ActionProxyFactory.class).createActionProxy(
>                   namespace, name, method, new HashMap(), true, false);

Any idea before I give up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else ends up in this post with the same issue

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ERROR CdiObjectFactory [findBeanManager]: Could not find BeanManager instance for any given JNDI key, giving up
ERROR CdiObjectFactory Struts2 CDI integration could not be initialized.
ERROR DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor Conversion registration error
```

You can fix this by excluding from your configuration struts2-cdi-plugin